# Rsync: skip files with sticky bit set

Tags: file-permissions, rsync

I am backing up an ext4 disk on Linux where some files have zero length and these funny permissions:

---------T. 2 myuser mygroup         0 Mar  5  2019 filename

From what I understand, they are leftovers from a previous glusterfs running on that disk, and can be safely skipped when copying the data. But rsync gives me this generic error, probably because of the missing read permission:

rsync: send_files failed to open "filename": Permission denied (13)

How can tell rsync to skip these files, based on the sticky bit set? I'd like to separate these from other possible problems with file permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsync does not seem to have anything specifically to handle this case, but what you can do is construct a list of files to exclude by using `find` beforehand. For example:

```sh
find dir -type f ! -perm /777 >list
rsync -a --exclude-from=list dir destdir
```

`-perm /777` finds files with at least one bit set in the modes 777, and `!` negates this.